# How to check if a value of a nested object already exists in another one?

Tags: angular, object, foreach, nested, comparison

I have a function in my angular application in which I have to go through the properties of a form and check which ones have the property "required" = true and then check if the user has already entered this information previously. With this validation I will skip the form if the corresponding user information already exists or I will show the form otherwise.

UPDATE

I've gone so far as to check if they have values through a couple of 'foreach' but I'm stuck at that point and I don't see how to solve what I need to do.

The function is the following

```
      const initForm = getInitForm();
      const user = getUser();
      const dataNotFilled = [];

      initialForm.props.forEach((prop) => {
        if (prop.required) {
          const nestedObjectData = {};

          Object.keys(user).forEach((initKey) => {

            const value = user[initKey];

            if (initKey === prop.name && value === null) {

              dataNotFilled.push(value);

            } else if (typeof value === 'object') {

              Object.assign(nestedObjectData, value);

              Object.keys(nestedObjectData).forEach((key) => {

                const nestedValue = nestedObjectData[key];

                if (key === prop.name && nestedValue === null) {

                  dataNotFilled.push(nestedValue);

                }

              });

            }

          });

          if (dataNotFilled.length) {
            browserHistory.push(ADD_USER_DATA_PATH);
          }

        }

      });
```

and this is the object of the required data of the form that I receive

```
{
  "label": "city",
  "name": "city",
  "type": "text",
  "parent": "primaryAddress",
  "validations": [
    {
      "message": "error",
      "value": {
        "pattern": "^\\d{2}-\\d{3}$|\\d{5}"
      },
      "rule": "regex"
    },
    {
      "message": "required",
      "value": true,
      "rule": "required"
    }
  ],
  "required": true,
  "services": []
}
```

and this is the object of the user

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Martin",
  "email": null,
  "address": null,
  "phone": {
    "home": null,
    "mobile": null
  },
  "address": {
    "code": "null",
    "address": null,
    "city": "Kansas"
  }
}
```

How can I compare the properties of both objects to skip the form if the information already exists?
thank you all for your time and help in advance.

Comment: are you using ```reactive forms```? If yes then you can go for ```Array<Forms>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making this too complex. Why not simply do something like this:

```
//Fill the form with your initial object, if any.
this.form = formBuilder.group({
    name: [{value: initialObject.name, disabled: initialObject.name !== null}] // Or '' or undefined
    surname: [{value: initialObject.surname, disabled: initialObject.surname !== null}]
})


// Other logic.

if(form.valid){
    // Form is instantly valid so skip it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow few steps:

- build form using `the object of the required data` (use some recursive function for this) with `formBuilder` as @robin-dijkhof metioned
- do `form.setValue( … )` passing `the object of the user`
- check if form is valid - should be if user data passes all validations

Use predefined `Validators.pattern` / `Validators.required` provided by angular ;)